# Rails: Getting an associated record from active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get all of a User's Items via their Liked Items, filtered by a string of the "list" column on Liked Items:

**models**

```
class LikedItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :liked_items
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :liked_items
  has_many :items, through: :liked_items
end
```

**controller**

```
@param = params[:filter]
  @importitems = @user.items
  @items = @importitems.left_joins(:liked_items)
                      .where('liked_items.list:' == @param)
```

**view**

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('<%= i.image.url(:large) %>')">

<% end %>
```

It is not filtering out by the liked_item.list — I'm getting all items returned

Comment: Look in which line the error occurs to find out how to solve it: `undefined method image for #LikedItem:0x00007ff2da89d2d8`
You're not mentioning `image` anywhere in your question, so we cannot really help you with that unless you post the relevant code/file.

Comment: updated to include the view that is supposed to render the image from the Item.

Comment: I'd check what @params is or even hardcode it in your `where('liked_items.list:' == 'the_value')`. I would even take another step back if that doesn't work and play in Rails Console to make sure you got the right data, params and query.